retrieved an file in jquery and send it to php
I'm trying to transfer an image retrieved in jquery from my html element (I use twig but I don't think it's important for this problem) input type="file" to my UserAjax.php thanks to $.ajax() but I only get a character string containing the name of my image
What I tried to do is transfer the File object but I got this error: TypeError: Illegal invocation and in some example I was able to find this.files[0].val() is used but I got the error that this is not a function. I am therefore looking to either be able to transfer the image, or the base 64 of the image to then process it.
I give you my code:
js :
$(document).on('change' , '#defined_avatar_file' , function(){
    filename = this.files[0];
    // console.log(this.files[0]);
    // console.log(this.files[0].val());
    var datas = {
        file_avatar : filename,
        // file : this.files[0],
    }

    $.ajax({
        url : 'index.php?action=modify-avatar-file',
        type : 'POST',
        data : datas,
        success : function(){

        }
    })
});

Edit :
thanks to ADyson I was able to find the solution I put it here it
could be useful
$(document).on('change' , '#defined_avatar_file' , function(){
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', $('#defined_avatar_file')[0].files[0]);
    $.ajax({
       url : 'index.php?action=modify-avatar-file',
       type : 'POST',
       data : formData,
       processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
       contentType: false,  // tell jQuery not to set contentType
       success : function(data) {
           console.log(data);
       }
    });
});

This sends my FormData object and for php recovery it is done like this:
var_dump($_FILES['file']['name']);
var_dump($_FILES['file']['size']);
...


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload

If you can see JavaScript error messages I get it that you're aware of browser developer tools. If no network request is generated, PHP code doesn't even have the chance to run so this is (at this step) purely a client-side problem.

Communication with my php is done correctly, the request is executed correctly, it is the data itself that is not correct

"it is the data itself that is not correct" - what does that mean? When you inspect the request, does it contain the data as expected? Is this a JS problem or a PHP problem?

as explained I can't receive the object and the file object, the only thing I managed to retrieve is the name of the image with this.files[0].name so I would say that the problem is js because I have the illegal error

Feel free to remove all irrelevant parts, and share more details about the relevant ones. If you think this is a JS problem, but are not sure: inspect the request. If you know that this is a JS problem: share your attempts to resolve it. For example, where did you define this.files?

When looking at JavaScript errors, click on the "Network" tab and find the request. There, you'll be able to see what is actually being sent ("Request" secondary tab). Currently, you're only doing indirect verifications that can mask many errors.
